# parsing ASP.NET Core connectionstring with Environtment= in systemd file

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, systemd

I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) 
To setup my ASP.NET Core app on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I'm having some trouble though. While It works when i set the appsettings.json connectionstring, it doesn't seem to be able to read one entered as it if put in the .service file like so `Environment=ConnectionStrings:SqlServer="connectionString"`

Is there a clever way to handle this? something I've missed maybe? 
I have used `systemd-escape "ConnectionStrings:SqlServer=\"<connectionString>\"` to make sure it's properly escaped, but it just seems the app never receives the connstr.

Supposedly I will have more than one service of these running at the same time, and they will NOT be using the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

To parse a sqlserver connectionstring, it must be added like so:

```
Environment:SQLCONNSTR_<stringname>=<connstring>
```

There are three other types as well, excluding the custom one. THey can be viewed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read this!

Comment: The variables in the question and answer don't match, it should also be two underscores. `ConnectionStrings__SqlServer` The value should be first escaped with `systemd-escape`

Comment: @ColinM it seems like the escaping of the string is noted in the question. And neither of the notations make use of any actual variables. I think what I wrote in the answers shows how it would be done well enough.

Comment: It does show how it would be done, but contains invalid syntax (`Environment:` instead of `Environment=`, `_` instead of `__`) and can be a bit confusing when you've changed the variable name from `ConnectionStrings` to `SQLCONNSTR` (rather than rely on a MS link, which they often break). Answers should help people, not send them further down a rabbit hole. I appreciate attitudes can come across wrong online over text so I would like to make it clear that I am only saying this to improve the quality of the answer to help others as this is the first SO question I see when Googling this.